# Magento API creates simple product correct -> but afterwards tells "101 Product not exists"

Tags: api, magento

I try to add some pictures to a simple product, which was created (without error) by the API. The product is shown in frontend its functional with all wanted attributes. But if I check afterwards

```
$client->call($sessionId, 'product.info', '123456');
```

I get Soap Error: "101: Product doesn't exists". But its definitivly reachable over back- and frontend. (Cache cleared, Index refreshed) 
Same issue, when I try to add media informations. On Confugurable Products the error don't show up and the pictures are added whithout any problems.

Maybe I messed something up with the attributes or the attribut sets... I don't know, where to watch first.

I'm at my php’s end!

Using Magento 1.6.0.0

Thank your for clarify me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this call with your product id instead of the sku? I had some problems in the past with product calls and the sku.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem! Doesn't even know thats possible to use id insted sku in the api.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ame API function ("product.info" in this case) receive as a parameter both SKU and ID, there is a problem if your are looking for SKU's which is numeric values.

To avoid this problem, we always adding space to the end of SKU before sending it to the API. For example, if your SKU is "123456" you should send "123456 " to the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed 2 magentos and we always use numeric SKUs and I've always had this problem.

I've solved it by modifying the file:
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api/Resource.php

About line 122 that reads:

```
$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, $this->_getStoreId($store), $identifierType);
```

I've changed it to:

```
$product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, $this->_getStoreId($store), 'sku');
```

This way the function always expects an SKU.